# Best way to store a variable on javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

In my app , I need to store  the username on the javascript frontend, I'm using `nodejs` with `twig` templates , and to get the username on the frontend I'm using this code on the template:

```
<script>
  var username = '{{username}}'
</script>
```

This way I have the `username` variable on the frontend that its what I need but , this variable is sent to the server on some functions and the problem its that any user can change its value on the browser console, my question its  , how I can store the variable to not be accesible to the users?

Comment: if you are using any server side language with JS, then u can use session.

Comment: `'How I can store the variable to not be accessible to the users?'` On the client-side you can't. As the JS runs on the client side and is accessible through the dev tools console any user can amend anything.

Comment: Using hidden input maybe

Comment: @Swati thats just obscuring the problem very very slightly. You can still change the value.

Comment: since you are using nodeJS, I can suggest using some kind of authentication  methods, like JWT. the user still can change it but he won't have the first clue of the result

Comment: I thoug on make an ajax request to get the username from de server side session

Answer (score 0):

If your user data is stored in database, you can just store the primary id of the record in a hidden input or in the cookie too.

When you send a request to server, pass that primary id and in server find the user record from database.
But in any case from the browser data can be tweaked.

To prevent that, you can use some kind of encryption/decryption.